# Как открыть текстовый файл, нажав на кнопку?

Tags: java, swing

Есть определенная кнопка. Когда пользователь нажимает на нее, должен открыться определенный текстовый файл. Для этого нужно создавать новый jFrame с
jTextArea на нем, или это по другому реализуется? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class JavaApplication extends JFrame { //класс окно
 JTextArea txaSome = new JTextArea();
 JButton btnSome = new JButton("Load file");

 final String THE_FILE = "/q.txt"; // адрес к читаемому файлу

 public static void main (String[] args) { //точка входа
  new JavaApplication();
 }

 public JavaApplication() { //конструктор
  setSize(800, 600);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  btnSome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //обработчик события
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    File file = new File(THE_FILE);
    String inner = "";

    try {
     BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //чтение файла

     int c;

     while((c = fr.read()) != -1) {
      inner += (char)c;
     }

     fr.close();
    } catch (IOException exc) {
     exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(inner);

    txaSome.setText(inner); //установка текста
   }
  });

  txaSome.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

  add(txaSome);
  add(btnSome);

  setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

При этом предполагается, что в `THE_FILE` содержится адрес файла, который необходимо прочитать, а JavaApplication - имя главного класса.

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, но ваш код не работает. Я работаю с Gui в Netbeans, но пытался разобраться с принципом работы вашего кода в Eclipse. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть какие-то другие варианты решения этой проблемы?

Comment: @Кот всё исправил, теперь работает.